# disable reusing same file_id for media

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

is there a way to disable reusing `file_id` for media? since it's lookup on database
and I want media reuploaded every time

I use copy message `client.send_meesage` on telethon and it's still looks up for `file_id` of image or video on database

i'm looking to make telethon to upload media instead of reuse `file_id` from database
as `client.send_file` can be done with `allow_cache=False`

I looked on docs, couldn't find anything related, and seem `allow_cache=False` not works with `client.send_meesage`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `telethon.sessions.string.StringSession`, this doesn't cache any data.

But probably you still want to cache the entities, so you can create your own class that inherits from one `telethon.sessions.sqlite.SQLiteSession` or `telethon.sessions.memory.MemorySession`, override the `get_file` method and make this returns always `None`. If you don't want to cache the files neither, must override `cache_file` method and make this just `pass`.

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.sessions import SQLiteSession

class NoFilesSession(SQLiteSession):

    def get_file(self):
        pass

    def cache_file(self):
        pass

client = TelegramClient(NoFilesSession('client'), API_ID, API_HASH)
```

This new session will mock the function `client.send_message`, making it trust  that there are no matches in the cache.

I recommend you to dive in the `telethon.sessions` package [source code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/tree/master/telethon/_sessions) and the [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/sessions.html) for the default types of sessions.

Comment: Hi again, I tried to add it to the code but still i'm getting same `file_id` and `file_unique_id`
here my code https://pastebin.com/q6vs77re

Comment: Hi, please share your code using the class `NoFilesSession` that I defined in the answer.

Comment: here https://pastebin.com/2NVm9FB2

Comment: In my answer, last line of the code I passed an instance of `NoFilesSession` to the `TelegramClient` initialization first argument. You aren't doing that and your code is using the default `SQLiteSession`. Fix at line 31 your client init, `client = TelegramClient(NoFilesSession(config["session_name"]), ...)`

Comment: I do, here https://pastebin.com/19HAAB7Y
but still I got same `file_unique_id`, the media is still has the same ID